# How to iterate over all <li> to get text contents from a handle to <ul> in PuppeteerJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a handle to a `<ul>` on the webpage I am scraping using Puppeteer like so:

```
const [detailElm] = await page.$x(
      "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul"
    );
```

Within this `<ul>` there are 7 `<li>` that I need to extract the text from. I have tried this:

```
const [detailElm] = await page.$x(
      "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul"
    );
const list = await detailElm.$x("li");

//this line prints 7 so I know that it is identifying the 7 <li>
console.log(list.length); 

//this doesn't work
for(line in list){
  console.log(list[line].innerText);
}
```

What would be the right way to iterate over the nested `<li>` elements instead of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElementHandle` doesn't have `innerHTML` property. You need to either use [`getProperty`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname):

```js
for (let line of list)
    console.log(await (await line.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue());
```

or pass the element to `evaluate`

```js
for (let line of list)
    console.log(await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, line);
```

Keep in mind that `forEach` is synchronous, so stick to the simple for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go with the forEach array operator?

```
 list.forEach(line => console.log(line))
```

Comment: Although that does iterate over the list, ```line.innerHTML``` returns undefined.

Comment: so It sounds like puppeteer isn’t returning the nodes themselves and is providing its own api... you should probably research puppeteer a bit